# Is there a very simple guide to install Three20 Library in new Xcode4 project?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode4, three20

I read its nice library.

But I don't understand why it is so complicated to install it.

Is there simple way to just download, and link the libraries ?

Answer (score 4):

http://three20.info/article/2011-03-10-Xcode4-Support

Comment: One line… doesn't get any simpler than that.

Comment: I found this link a bit more helpful than the above: http://chepri.com/2011/04/22/visual-guide-manually-adding-three20-xcode-4-project/

Answer (score 0):

I suggest playing with the sample apps and reading some of the three20's manual before you add three20 to your project. That's how you can get a feeling of what the framework can do.

After that, create a new project and follow http://three20.info/article/2010-10-06-Adding-Three20-To-Your-Project